# Discord bot - send DM to mentioned user

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I want make bot that will send message to user that I mention
for example I will type !hello @thomas#5555

And bot will send DM message "hello" to this user

```
if(message.content.startsWith(prefix + "sendHello")){
    const taggedUser = message.mentions.users.first();
    const user = client.users.cache.get(taggedUser.id);
    user.send('Hello');
    }
```

What's wrong?
Keep getting this:
"ReferenceError: client is not defined"

I defined client on the top of the code like this:
"const Client = new Disocrd.Client();"

Comment: taggedUser is already a user, you don't need to make a 2nd variable

Comment: Can you add your complete code as it seems that the error might be because of how you declare your client at the top

Answer (score 0):

Since you defined your client as `Client`, you need to use that instead of `client`. You could also use `message.client` to access it from the message object.

Comment: So I changed everywhere in code "Client" to "client" but now It showing this error:
"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')"

Comment: Send the full error please

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you are [initializing your Client](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/#creating-the-main-file) correctly.

Try:

```js
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });
```

With discord.js v13 you need to add the intents you want your Client to receive. The `Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS` intents option is necessary for your client to work properly. You can see all [Intents here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Intents?scrollTo=s-FLAGS).

Also for your command code, if someone tagged a User you don't need to fetch the User again. Just use the `taggedUser` variable.

```js
const taggedUser = message.mentions.users.first(); // get User
if (!taggedUser) return message.channel.send('Please mention a user to fetch.'); // Check to see if a User was tagged.
taggedUser.send('Hi') // send to User
```